# Suppose that $ \tau $ is a topology on $ \mathbb{R}$ that contains all closed intervals

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $ \tau $ is a topology on $ \mathbb{R}$ that contains **all closed intervals**. Prove that $ \tau $ is the **discrete** topology on $ \mathbb{R}$.

**Answer:**

Since $ \tau $ contains all closed intervals, all the intervals $ [a,b] , \ \ a,b \in \mathbb{R} $ are open set in $ \tau $. Let $ \epsilon >0 $ be a real number. Then  $ [x-\epsilon, x] \cap [x,x+1]=\{x\} \in \tau $ for all x.

So every singleton is open in $ \tau $.

So $ \tau $ is discrete .

**Am I right ?**

Comment: I think you should show that the discrete topology also gives rise to the 'closed interval' topology to show that they're equivalent.

Comment: Since the closed interval [x,x] = {x}, singletons are open.

Comment: You are right but you don't need $\epsilon$ because $[-1+x]\cap [x,x+1]=\{x\}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: please mark or vote up my question

Comment: I think the answer is too verbose.

Comment: @copper.hat . I saw a good one-word answer to the Q "Alternatives to math?" on this site.